# Calculate and plot line spread function using intensity data points from image

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, lenses, image-processing

I am working on a project and I am wondering how to depict a graph of the Line Spread function. I have pixel intensity across a knife/slanted edge, a range of about 40 data points. I have successfully created a plot of the edge spread function, and I have taken the slope of each pair of points in attempt of plotting line spread through the derivative. However, when compared to an online software, the peak of my line spread graph is not nearly as high as it should be. I cannot find methods for the software online. Any ideas on how to plot line spread directly from data points? Thanks!

Comment: How wide is your instrument response function? What you are measuring is always a convolution between the actual physical intensity and the instrument response. There are also sampling theorem and numerical problems with the differentiation algorithm, all of which will cause significant errors if not controlled properly.